# How to create a type with all properties from Type1 or all properties from Type2 in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have some code like this:

```
interface Notification {
  message: TemplatedEmail & Email, //current attempt which doesnt do what I want
}

interface Destination {
  ccAddresses?: string[],
  bccAddresses?: string[],
  toAddresses: string[]
}

interface TemplatedEmail {
  destination: Destination,
  source: string,
  template: string,
  templateData: any,
  replyToAddresses?: string[]
}

interface Email {
  destination: Destination,
  source: string,
  body: string,
  subject: string,
  replyToAddresses?: string[]
}
```

I want the `message` property of `Notifications` to be of type `Email` or `TemplatedEmail`, by this I mean that either all properties (optional can be skipped ofcourse) of `Email` should be available in `message` or all properties of `TemplatedEmail`. With Union Types, I can only access the properties common to both the types and with intersection types, I get all the properties of both types.

With my current code, something like this doesnt work:

```
const x: Notification = { 
    message: {
          destination: { toAddresses: [ "" ] },
          source: "",
          body: "",
          subject: ""
    }
};
```

It complains that properties `template` and `templateData` are missing from `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) but this would change a bit the structure of your message:

```
type XType = TemplateNotification | EmailNotification;

interface TemplateNotification {
  kind: 'template',
  message: TemplatedEmail
}

interface EmailNotification {
  kind: 'email',
  message: Email
}

const x: XType = { 
    kind: 'email',
    message: {
          destination: { toAddresses: [ "" ] },
          source: "",
          body: "",
          subject: ""
    }
};
```

playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBADQCrXgXjkmBbKAbAQzBgDkB7MASwDNKBjIysgOzgB84BRbAyvcqrQZUWAblCVmxAE7UCdeFlyFiAmvUYs4Ab1Bw4Aa0kATAFxwA5MWVEYFgDR642GAGdXBAOYxzS-LeNuXjxQAF8JKRhZeXggvjUhTVZdEH0jZjNLHGCHJxd3Lx8uHj4w0AiZOQU4ABE3KmYknSc6OgBBY2NpN1c3AH5zVzBpSU8AbQBdR1S4ACNWjq6e-sHh0cnp-TAyRe73N1WR5nGJspAKqKrFHH9iQJK8Zpnjeskk8zqht5FmTbhXMgAV2kCkOoz+1luRSGR08EJuKhgNSIBHMBGYED+3XwECQO06e16rgG-zWx0mZwu0WqcUeKX0Ly+jR+H1ezKYvycAOBoNJsL+szIxggYOOf1cgNmACsYHQwKK4U5sXhcfilvtiQqKSBwucQHQWEM4AAPczIVBwDDaOBONImcwWbJ8XIzfT5Dzecz0-Q+32MhrvHRwba7ZaucxjOAAIijcAmcFCf19vu5IKKMaTyf0guF5gztqz-0lMrleajBd1oVEQA)

Comment: Your code isnt complete, finish it and then see the error for yourself, the link is too long so I cant put it in a comment.

Comment: Why did you change `Notification` to `INotification`? In your updated code, hen I do `console.log(x.message.body);`, I get `Property 'body' does not exist on type 'TemplatedEmail | Email'.
  Property 'body' does not exist on type 'TemplatedEmail'.`

Comment: Union types only give access to properties available in both the types.

Comment: interface Notification is reserved in TS Playground and comes from lib.dom.d.ts, that's why I had to change it to INotification. You wouldn't have this issue in your module. I now read that you tried using union so I edited my answer to fit better your requirements. hope this helps

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thanks. I will wait and see if there are some other ways to achieve this and then accept this as the answer.